# File explorer in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a video decoder application on Xcode 4.2. When I click on a button I need the file explorer to open so that I can choose the appropriate file to decode.

How do I give this file explorer option in my app?

Answer (score 1):

There no such thing like file explorer in iOS .So you cant browse through the files in the iOS .At the most you can access the camera roll . Apple doesnt allow to access the other things like songs,other file etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
So, what is equivalent to file explorer in iOS? How can I choose the input file that I want?